# SuiteScript 2.0: Merge sales orders into one

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

We receive multiple sales orders where each one has its own *ship to* customer, but they share the same bill to customer.
Our current idea is to:

1. Create the SO (scheduled script)
2. Create the fulfillment (manually)
3. Close the SO (map reduce script)
4. Create a global SO (map reduce script)
5. Create a global invoice (map reduce script)

In your opinion, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a better approach.

Leave the native transactions alone and invoice normally but don't auto send the invoices.

A couple of approaches I've taken is to do either of the following:

1. create detailed statement that lists the items on all the invoices for a date range. Customer gets a single document and can send a single payment that you can apply.
2. create a custom record that groups invoices by customer. This is usefu if you might be invoicing over odd periods or need to do project invoiceing or anything were a simple montly statement doesn't group your consolidated invoice properly. Getting fancy would allow you to script a payment allocation (though I think recent versions of Netsuite handle this quite well)

The best way to approach this though requires an understanding of why your company feels the need to consolidate.